# matplotlib set_xticklabels shift 1 position

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have list of number

```py
scores = [0.4126984126984127,
 0.9841269841269841,
 0.9841269841269841,
 0.3333333333333333,
 0.6825396825396826,
 0.7301587301587301,
 0.9841269841269841,
 0.4603174603174603,
 1.0]

names = ["Nearest Neighbors", "Linear SVM", "RBF SVM", "Gaussian Process",
         "Decision Tree", "Random Forest", "Neural Net", 
         "AdaBoost",
         "Naive Bayes"
        ]
```

I would like to plot the y-axis the scores and x-axis names of them then.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, axs = plt.subplots()
axs.plot(scores)
axs.set_xlabel("classifier names")
axs.set_ylabel("Score")
axs.set_xticklabels(names, rotation=90)
```

I got warning and the x-axis is shift by one and I lost it!
[image]

In the picture nearest neighbor is lost and the rest of them are shifted

**Question**

How to solve this error?

Answer (score 1):

matplotlib does not automatically calculate xticks. I have to put it myself

```
axs.set_xticks([i for i in range(9)])
```